# Node.js code being skipped (for)

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, asynchronous

I cannot see what's happening here, can someone enlighten me?

Why am I not entering the FOR?
Code:

```
console.log('l:269');

var smallestPrice = itemPriceAll; // start with max
console.log('itemNames.length, itemPriceall: ' + itemNames.length + ' ' + itemPriceAll);
for (var y; y < itemNames.length; y++) {
    console.log('Are you fucking kidding me?');
    console.log('l:272, itemPrice: ' + itemPrice[y] + 'houseEdge: ' + (itemPriceAll * houseEdge));
    if (itemPrice[y] >= (itemPriceAll * houseEdge)) {
        console.log('l:274');
        if (itemPrice[y] < smallestPrice) {
            smallestPrice = itemPrice[y]; 
            keeping = itemId[y]; 
        }
    }
}

console.log('l:284');
```

Output:

```
l:269
itemNames.length, itemPriceall 23 97
l:284
```

Comment: for(var y = 0; y < itemNames.length; y++) perhaps?

Comment: @neilsimp1, worked, im so pissed haha :P thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

In your `for` loop, your condition is `y < itemNames.length`, but the initial value of `y` is `undefined`.  Thus, the condition is falsy.  If you want to do a numeric comparison, you should initialize `y` to a numerical value.

I'd suggest `var y = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var y = 0; y < itemNames.length; y++)
```

was it; I expected y to be empty and numeric.

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/4265939/neilsimp1